# what's in a name: Bias?

Tags: bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm studying machine learning and one of the key points I make sure is to understand the origin and the reasoning why such a name or term is used. It could be a rich and insightful dive into the concept it is trying to convey.

So, about bias-variance trade-off. Why use the word 'bias'?

In the usual, everyday parlance, 'bias' means leaning towards one side. If in the case of explaining pros and cons of a certain ideology, to be 'biased' means to give an unbalanced view and lean towards something.

Can we say the same for machine learning?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, this is not what is meant by a 'self-study' question. That refers mostly to homework or routine exercises.

Comment: Wikipedia adequately defines the *meaning* of (estimation) [bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) (& it *does* carry a sense of leaning toward one side); it has a section on bias, variance and MSE, and if you look at [Bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) you'll see the direct connection to that section.  As for its origins, the term has been around in statistical writing since the late 19th century: See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (B)](http://jeff560.tripod.com/b.html) (and then search on 'bias').

Comment: ... and almost any reasonable text with a section on estimation will have extensive discussion of bias (among numerous other relevant properties of estimators); it's standard fare in statistics-degree programs.

Comment: You may also be interested in the electronics variety of the term bias: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing.